# Fail2Ban not banning

Tags: fail2ban

Fail2Ban works fine with the built-in jails, but my custom OpenVPN jail doesn't ban anything, neither does my NGINX-DoS jail. The output of `sudo fail2ban-client status openvpn` is:

```
Status for the jail: openvpn
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 0
|  `- File list:    /var/log/openvpn.log
- Actions
|- Currently banned:    2
|- Total banned:    2
`- Banned IP list:  1.2.3.4 1.3.4.5
```

I changed the IP addresses, BTW. So the jail is working, but the output of `iptables-save | grep 1.2.3.4` returns nothing, so the IP is not being blocked. All other jails work fine.

My `openvpn.conf` file in `filter.d` is:

```
# Fail2Ban filter for selected OpenVPN rejections
#
#
[INCLUDES]

before = common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = ^ TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from \
[AF_INET\]<HOST>:\d+$
        ^ <HOST>:\d+ Connection reset, restarting
        ^ <HOST>:\d+ TLS Auth Error
        ^ <HOST>:\d+ TLS Error: TLS handshake failed$
        ^ <HOST>:\d+ VERIFY ERROR

ignoreregex =
```

and the section in `jail.local` is:

```
[openvpn]
enabled  = true
port     = 1194
protocol = tcp
backend = auto
filter   = openvpn
logpath  = /var/log/openvpn.log
action = sendmail[name=openvpn, dest=my_email@my_domain.com]
banaction = iptables-multiport
```

The same thing is happening with my NGINX jail, fail2ban-client says its banned, and I get an email saying an IP was banned, but nothing happens.

Comment: i use `iptables -S | grep fail2ban` to get the banned ips. I think it's more appropiate than `iptables-save` which has a specific saving purpose.

Comment: Still no output though

Comment: The problem is not recording them, it does that just fine. The problem is that they don't get banned.

Comment: Yes, but not the IPs that are supposed to be banned by the OpenVPN jail. The only problem is that jail, other jails ban IPs just fine

Comment: Forget my previous comments.  I believe that the filter might not be created properly.  I think some of the info out there is outdated since the newer release.  I know that none of my previous custom filters that I had worked, so I only turned on my sshd one for now.  I even had to turn off my permanent banning as it no longer worked either.

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo iptables -S f2b-openvpn`?

Comment: One other thought here.   When someone tries to log into your host, it is logged in the `/var/log/auth.log`.  You might need to change your log path, or look to see which files are containing the text `TLS Error:`

Comment: Mine works, and is generally similar to what you have, but I have `protocol=udp` in the `jail.local`. AFAIK openvpn defaults to udp.

Comment: I set my OpenVPN server to 1194 TCP so it can work behind a port multiplexer

Answer (score 1):

According to the fail2ban Wiki you might want to try setting `protocol = udp` instead of `protocol = tcp`. [www.fail2ban.org Wiki](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_fail2ban_with_OpenVPN)

Your banaction 'iptables-multiport' will create a new iptables chain with all banned ips and add this chain to iptables INPUT chain.
You can check if this chain is being created correctly with `iptables -vnL`. Look for a 'f2b-openvpn' chain at the 'Chain INPUT' section at the top of that output and then a 'CHAIN f2b-openvpn' section with all the banned IPs further down that output.

Also consider obfuscating your mail address from you config example.